# Font sizes/weight not being maintained in Kendo-react-pdf

Tags: kendo-react-ui

I am using kendo-react-pdf `@progress/kendo-react-pdf` to one of the products i am building to export a list view and it is observed that the export is not maintaining the font sizes and font weight (even with system fonts). I use Styled-components to style.  Has anyone faced this before ?